# Dealing with duplicate emails using MailChimp

Tags: php, html, forms, mailchimp, mailing-list

I've inherited some code which allows an interested party to subscribe to our newsletter.

The form's action attribute takes the user to `http://ourcompany.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1&amp;id=1` where it says "we need you to confirm, please check your email" and then it redirects back to our site. If the users clicks on this link in their email, it then subscribes the user.

If the user enters their e-mail address a second time it takes them to `http://ourcompany.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1&amp;id=1` and shows a form where they can edit their profile, but it's unbranded, verbose and not what we want to show our users.

Instead, we'd rather take the user to a branded form we've created for updating their profile, which is included in the email's footer, with the URL of `http://ourcompany.us7.list-manage.com/profile?u=1&id=1&e=1`.

Is there any way to modify MailChimp's form or sign-up process to have this happen?

Here's the (reduced) form,

```
<form action="http://ourcompany.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1&amp;id=1" method="post">
    <label>Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a simple MailChimp configurable way of doing this?

Comment: @Chris I believe so, but I honestly forget what I had to do. I'm really sorry about that :/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to design the signup alert page on mail-chimp forum

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-build-and-design-my-signup-form-and-response-emails

or if you used your branded form you will need custom coding to subscribe users to mailchimp i see that you used embed forms.

For custom coding here is the link for documentation

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php